# Broken Touch Display, Cannot Login: 20.04

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, touchscreen

I'm running 20.04 on a Lenovo Idea Pad with a broken touch screen. I disable the touch screen via Xorg once I'm in the desktop, post login.

However, the login screen still has the touch screen enabled and it makes it very difficult to type in my username and password, as the broken touch screen detects screen presses and fills the entry boxes with junk.

I spent some time trying to disable the driver, however everything I tried also disabled my track pad.

```
sudo modprobe -r hid_multitouch
```

The BIOS doesn't not have a choice to disable the touch screen.

I'm not wedded to my current desktop choice of Gnome, and fine with a different one.

TIA

EDIT: I'd like to learn more about device drivers. If someone knows how to disable my display from being grabbed by `hid-multitouch` that would be great.

[Lenovo specific driver details](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-lenovo.c)